# What is the best way to manage permissions as root installing postgresql and postgis?

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, postgis-2.0, linux

I've encountered an issue numerous times where I lock myself out of my postgres installation as a result of modifying my pg_hba.conf file and therefore screw up my postgres installation because I don't have root access. So I want to manage everything as root and create all the right users with permissions and then use my linux terminal only installation as a non-root user and still be able to manage everything necessary while limiting my user access to pg_hba.conf.

Ergo, if I want to have my postgresql installation open-ended and accessible what settings do I need to make in pg_hba. And by that I mean I want to connect remotely using tcp/ip.

Comment: use sudo before editing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo